# How to custom wordpress query fields,let query without post_content while showing front page?

Tags: wordpress

I hope my WordPress front page show only the title.
I could add filter to the 'the_content' hook so that will not show post content,
but this operation the wp_query function also search post_content fields.
how to custom the wp_query do not query post_content fields while execute SQL clause.the reason for this requirement was i set front page show hundreds of posts.

Comment: Hello Tonvin, please explain me your question properly in brief. so i can give you solution.

Comment: Thank you,briefly,the front page show posts without content,and let the query SQL do not search post_content field.